# Syntax error in K&R style function definition, why?

Tags: c, syntax

```
#include <stdio.h>
long int faktorijal(n);
int n;
{
if (n==0)
return((long)1);
else
return(n*faktorijal(n-1)); // Recursive call
}
main()
{
int i;
for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
printf("%d! = %d\n",i,faktorijal(i));
getch();
}
```

Gives me an error "[Error] expected identifier or '(' before '{' token".

I think it has something to do with main functions, but I'm not sure so I'm asking here.

**faktorijal means factorial**

**EDIT**: Just goes to show how wrong books can be. It's an older book, but we're also being taught to use getch() instead of getchar or return 0.

Thanks guys, this helped out a lot.

Comment: `main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: Please indent your code!

Comment: You really should get a new keyboard. Your spacebar does not work in code snippets. And K&R-style function declarators are an obsolescence feature and should never be used. If you use a book for learning: please get a new one aboutt modern C (at least C99, better standard C(11) ).

Comment: @Olaf Now, that, is a wise comment, seriously. :)

Comment: @Olaf - yep, it's a school book. The reason I'm indenting in such way is because I wanted it to be 100% like it's written in the book, and it's still wrong! Thanks.

Comment: how old is that school book? just wondering it has to be ancient :)

Comment: Not sure xander - I don't have the starting/ending pages. I'd guess over 10 years.

Comment: @alcatraz: 1) Indentation is to make code human-readable. If your book does not use indentation/spaces, it is rubbish from the beginning. 2) No serious programmer will accept this coding style. not for the indentation, not for the function-declaration. 3) Get a new book and throuh that one out of the window. It was outdated 18 years ago already.

Comment: @xander: Doesn't "school book about programming" imply "ancient"? ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using [K&R style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R). In this case

```
 long int faktorijal(n);
 int n;
```

the trailing `;` after the function signature is wrong. Remove that.

After that,

- `faktorijal()` returns a `long int`, but you're providing the return value as argument to `%d` which is again wrong. You need to use `%ld` for that.
- `getch()` is not a standard library function, use `getchar()` instead.
- The conforming signature of `main()` as per the C standard (*latest, if you argue*), for a hosted environment, is at least `int main(void)`. The implicit int rule has been explicitly removed from the standard.

Comment: function prototype i think .

Comment: I up-voted your answer because it is complete, to the point and well referenced. But in general, answering this sort of typo question is a waste of energy. They usually get closed fast and deleted in a community moderation effort.

Comment: @StoryTeller OK, sure...just thought maybe it will be helpful to someone as chances of running into these kind of problem is also very slim, so took the oppertunity to clarify a few points. However, will refrain in future, thanks. :)

Comment: Please don't let me discourage you from answering. Just bear that in mind  if you see the effort to answer becomes substantial.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sure, will do. Been back after a long time, good to see that the community is as helpful as it used to be...Cheers!!

Comment: @StoryTeller: Problem is, the up-votes will prevent the question from automatic deletion after some time after closure. Thus deletion keeps real people busy. Such question should not be answered in general, better put the effort into better questions. (oh, and the syntax error would also exist for a prototype-declarator)

Answer (score 0):

**1.**  The function :

```
long int faktorijal(n);
int n;
{
    if (n==0)
        return((long)1);
    else
        return(n*faktorijal(n-1)); // Recursive call
}
```

is not written correctly. Change it to :

```
long int faktorijal(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return((long)1);
    else
        return(n*faktorijal(n-1)); // Recursive call
}
```

**2.** Also change :

```
printf("%d! = %d\n",i,faktorijal(i));
```

to :

```
printf("%d! = %ld\n",i,faktorijal(i));
```

as the specifier for `long int` is `%ld`. The specifier `%d` is for `int`s.

**3.** Change the declaration of `main` from :

```
main(){}
```

to :

```
int main(){}
```

**4.** Finally change :

```
getch();
```

to :

```
getchar();
```

and include `stdlib.h`.

Comment: In second case, you're missing the type...it's wrong. you're shadowing...

Comment: @NatashaDutta what do you mean second case?

Comment: Thanks, this alone taught me a lot about long ints. Appreciate it.

Comment: @alcatraz Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following block of code:

```
long int faktorijal(n);
int n;
{
if (n==0)
return((long)1);
else
return(n*faktorijal(n-1)); // Recursive call
}
```

To:

```
long int faktorijal(int n) // remove semicolon from here, this is function header. Also defined data type of argument
{
    if (n==0)
        return((long)1);
    else
        return(n*faktorijal(n-1)); // Recursive call
}
```

When you define a function, there should not be a semicolon between the header and the opening curly brace of the function body. The compiler expects the closing parenthesis right before the opening curly bracket here, that is why it produces an error saying:

> [Error] expected identifier or '(' before '{' token

You also forgot to specify the data type of the parameter. Remove `n` from the function argument header and instead, add the `int n` over there instead, like shown in the corrected code.

**Also**, you forgot to define `main()` properly:

```
main()
```

C++ syntax for the `main()` function requires it to have a return data type of int. Therefore, change your main function to:

```
int main()
```

**Another thing:** your `printf()` statement uses an incorrect format specifier. Change:

```
printf("%d! = %d\n",i,faktorijal(i));
```

To:

```
printf("%d! = %ld\n",i,faktorijal(i));
```

This is because `faktorijal(i)` returns a `long int`, and the format specifier for a long int is `%ld`

Comment: This will not work. Did you try compiling it?

Comment: @Marievi just fixed it.